# Convert RadioButton control to check box control in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

We have a menustrip in our link button. I have added an item which contains child items that are radio buttons and checkboxes. If a user selects a radio button on the form and in the menustrip they select a checkbox item then it should convert to checkbox control including all its properties i.e fore color ,back color font size ,font style etc.

So could you please help me to convert a radio button control to a checkbox control during the run-time of the form.

Comment: Is there any solution to this post

Answer (score 3):

The [RadioButton](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton%28v=vs.80%29.aspx&ei=pNAPUOPnGYKe0QX8_YGwBg&usg=AFQjCNGBVFlAZeFiH189af7wAx9JoT3i9w) control cannot be converted to a [Checkbox](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.aspx&ei=jdAPUJDFEOTs0gWp8YB4&usg=AFQjCNGFYD-Nns3NbZ95Ud7q-eenA-SvRw) control because they are not in inheritance hierarchy.

However if you need to do that, you can create a [Checkbox](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.aspx&ei=jdAPUJDFEOTs0gWp8YB4&usg=AFQjCNGFYD-Nns3NbZ95Ud7q-eenA-SvRw) control copying the properties that are common for then, and you need to reuse, and then, switch their visibility:

```
    private CheckBox GetCheckboxFromRadioButton(RadioButton radioButton)
    {
        CheckBox result = new CheckBox();
        //copy text
        result.Text = radioButton.Text;
        //copy colors
        result.BackColor = radioButton.BackColor;
        result.ForeColor = radioButton.ForeColor;
        //copy checked state
        result.Checked = radioButton.Checked;
        //copy parent container
        result.Parent = radioButton.Parent;
        //copy size and location
        result.Bounds = radioButton.Bounds;
        //copy layout behavior
        result.Dock = radioButton.Dock;
        result.Anchor = radioButton.Anchor;
        //enabled property
        result.enabled = radioButton.Enabled;
        // copy other properies you need here
        //...
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function

```
CheckBox ConvertControl(RadioButton rb)
```

and implement Checkbox creation with every property initialization you need. Since controls are different they have some sprcific properties which will be impossible to convert automatically - you should soecify how they should be inited explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
    private void RadioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton1.Checked = !(bool)RadioButton1.Tag ;
    }

    private void RadioButton1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton1.Tag = RadioButton1.Checked;
    }
```